# Is it possible to return to normal mode in the middle of a vim command?

Tags: regular-expression, visual-mode, replace, range

By simply calling `:(range)g/bob/norm Axxx` I can add `xxx` to the to the end of all lines in `range` containing `bob`. Is there a way to return to normal mode after having used A/I/a/i to enter insert  mode, all within a command, in order to perform more actions to the matching lines without starting another command?

Comment: `:help :bar` seems to be what you what to read

Comment: @user642832 So? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that we're using the global command to surround each matching line with brackets. (*This is not really a good way to bracket text. It's just for illustration here.*)

You hinted at maybe inserting an <kbd>Esc</kbd> somewhere in there. Perhaps like this...

```
:g/bob/ norm! A}<ESC>I{
```

But that approach won't work.

Others might have a first instinct to try something like this:

```
:g/bob/ norm! A} | norm! I{
```

Alas, this won't work either. Both these cases see everything after the opening `A` as text to be appended.

Digging deeper into the second approach, if we look at `:h :norm` we'll find the following:

> This command cannot be followed by another command, since any '|' is considered part of the command.

Fortunately we can get around this by embedding that first `:norm` command in an `execute` call (`:h :exe`)...

```
:g/bob/ exe "norm! A}" | norm! I{
```

That does the trick. Using `:exe` allows us to implicitly signal the end of the first `:norm`.

Note that this is a generally applicable solution that answers the question "How do I follow `:norm` with another command?".

Comment: If it is used in place (not inside a script) i would prefer to insert a literal Escape: g/bob/norm! A}<C-v><Esc>I{

Comment: @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz If you're talking about those times that one enters a command manually I would tend to use Ctrl-V myself. In any other scenario, including when providing answers here, I avoid Ctrl-V. Such commands are very often ambiguous to folks who aren't familiar so extra explanatory text is necessary. And they frequently cause trouble for people who unknowingly try to copy/paste such commands.